# How to count if value of a variable is repeated?

Tags: php, mysql

I am learning how to work with MySQL, and at the moment I succeed to show data from my table, using:

```
while($objResult2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($objQuery_product)) {
```

Results are shown by using this variable `$objResult2["id_product"];` this way i can take from DB any field I want like: `$objResult2["name"];` `$objResult2["email"];` etc.

But what i do if i have in the table more rows with the same `id_product`?

I want to write a `if` statment, which counts if `id_product` repeats. How to do that? If it is a lot of work, atleast please give me an idea of the right tutorial that I must read. Because i am trying second day to fix this, and searched google but i didnt find what i need, or maybe i coulndt understand it....

**This is my query**

```
$sql_product = "SELECT * FROM ps_product AS prod";
$join_product = " LEFT JOIN ps_product_lang AS lang ON lang.id_product = prod.id_product";
$join2_product = " LEFT JOIN ps_stock_available AS stok ON stok.id_product = prod.id_product";
$where_product =" WHERE prod.id_category_default = $idp AND lang.id_lang = 8";

$sql_product = $sql_product.$join_product.$join2_product.$where_product;
$objQuery_product = mysqli_query($objConnect, $sql_product) or die ("Error Query [".$sql_product."]");
```

Comment: do you want to check if the id_product is more than 1?

Answer (score 0):

Ok here we go. For example you are fetching data with this query.

```
select id_product, name from PRODUCTS;
```

Suppose above query gives you 5 records.

id_product name
1          bat 
2          hockey
2          hockey
3          shoes
4          gloves

Now you got 2,2 and hockey, hockey. Instead of thinking this way that you have to introduce an if statement to filter repeating records or same name or id_product records.

> **Rewrite your sql query like this.**

```
select distinct id_product, name from PRODUCTS;
```

Or if you need count of each then my friend you will write your query something like this...

Graham Ritchie, if Andrei needs count of each repeating record then we will do something like this in our query.

```
SELECT PRODUCT_ID, 
 COUNT(PRODUCT_ID) AS Num_Of_Occurrences
FROM PRODUCTS
GROUP BY PRODUCT_ID
HAVING ( COUNT(PRODUCT_ID) > 1 );
```

Comment: I think he wants to know how to see if there are more than one of a product with a specific id - this shows all unique id's

Answer (score 0):

You can simple remove the same `id_product` using `DISTINCT` keyword in your query. Such as:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id_product FROM my_table
```

This will give you results with different ids only.

The second way of doing it is taking the output values inside an array.

In your while loop:

```
$my_array[] = $objResult2["id_product"];
```

Then using `array_filter` remove all the duplicates inside the array.
YOu can also use `array_count_values()` if you want to count the duplicate values.

Comment: the second part is what i also thought of, like an ideea...but dont it must look like: $my_array[] = $objQuery_product;?

Comment: `$my_array[] = $objResult2["id_product"];` will give you an associative array. Then you can perform your `array_count_values()` to  count the duplicates and remove then using `array_filter`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id_product,COUNT(*) AS count 
FROM tablename 
GROUP BY id_product;
```

This query will then return you two items in your query

```
$objResult2["id_product"] //and
$objResult2["count"]
```

The if statement is then just

```
if($objResult2["count"] > 1){
    //Do whatever you want to do with items with more than 1 occurence.
    //for this example we will echo out all of the `product_id` that occur more than once.

    echo $objResult2["id_product"] . " occurs more than once in the database<br/>";
}
```